# Regex for any word, square bracket, asc OR desc OR any other string(s) delimited by comma, square bracket

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling with regex for the following construct.  The preferred language is Java.

> any word, square bracket, asc OR desc OR any other string(s) delimited by comma (but when there are multiple words delimited by comma asc or desc can't appear there), square bracket

I've come up with this but it doesn't work correctly.

```
^.*?\[(asc|desc|([a-zA-Z0-9]+,?)+?)\]$
```

Testing data:

```
hl[asc]
dd[desc]
pa[asc]
ldka[1azqmrueq0081po5uc1g16jot,1azqmrueq0081po5uc1g16jot,default]
poa[3oihkx5wfar7qu9nvqruhrn17]
ppa[dspxu1o2l06bzbh84m9luu701,f8ir6cuq4unhgi0a4kqjwidb0]
```

Testing data not matched:

```
bb[asc,]
ca[desc,]
dd[asc,1azqmrueq0081po5uc1g16jot]
ge[1azqmrueq0081po5uc1g16jot,desc]
```

Comment: Please, show input and output examples (test data).

Comment: Any preferred language? Options may differ per language.

Comment: What are "asc" and "desc"? Ascending & descending seems odd here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that what is in between square brackets does not contain a word followed by a comma and asc or desc or vice versa:

```
^(?![^[]+\[[^]]*(?:\w+,\s*\b(?:asc|desc)\b|\b(?:asc|desc)\b,\s*\w+)[^]]*\]).+$
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "^(?![^\\[]+\\[[^]]*(?:\\w+,\\s*\\b(?:asc|desc)\\b|\\b(?:asc|desc)\\b,\\s*\\w+)[^]]*\\]).+$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFmkR6/1/)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead
- `[^[]+\[[^]]*(?:\w+,(?:asc|desc)|(?:asc|desc),\w+)[^]]*\]` Details:

  - `[^[]+` Negated character class to match not `[` 1+ times
  - `\[` Match literally
  - `[^]]*` Negated character class to match not `]` 0+ times
  - `(?:` Non capturing group with alternation to match either

    - `\w+,\s*\b(?:asc|desc)\b` Match 1+ word characters followed by comma and asc or desc
    - `|` Or
    - `\b(?:asc|desc)\b,\s*\w+` Match asc or desc followed by a comma and 1+ word characters
  - `)` Close non capturing  group
  - `[^]]*` Negated character class to match not `]` 0+ times
  - `\]` Match `]` literally
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `.+` Match any character 1+ times
- `$` Assert the end of the string

[Demo Java](https://ideone.com/hMZCwC)

Comment: thank you but so far this isn't compilable, nevertheless going to examine this to try where is the error (there is more closing brackets than opening)

Comment: @aRagornol I have updated the Java version. There was an unescaped `[` and I have added a [Demo](https://ideone.com/hMZCwC)

Comment: sir you truly are regex master :) I will need to study this how it works. thank you very much

Comment: one more question if you don't mind ? can this be reworked so groups can be returned ? like group 1 what's before brackets, group 2 what's inside brackets ?

Comment: @aRagornol Sure, you could use 2 capturing groups: [Java demo](https://ideone.com/WySvvp) and [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEzjm4/1). This uses a negated character class to match not a newline or `[]` inside the square brackets. You could always change that to a character class to specify what you would allow to match instead.